# Does c++ support drawing graphics by itself?

Tags: c++, graphics

In the old days(those of Borland) you could use the graphics.h header file in c and c++ to draw graphics like lines, squares or circles. This was supported by turbo c++.

Nowadays, I guess the recommended way of drawing graphics is using OpenGL or DirectX.

I just wish to know if there still exists a way to draw basic graphics like lines in c++, similar to the way we used to do in tc++. If yes, how?

**Why:** This all started when I couldn't solve a problem in a competition that asked me to draw some curves using c++. They were using tc++(!?!) and expected us to use graphics.h header file.

I had no knowledge of doing this, because I didn't expect I would ever need to draw graphics in c++ this(outdated) way. Anyway I  am still trying to find a solution where I use modern compilers like gcc(g++) and still bypass OpenGL. I don't want to go back to tc++.

BTW I am using Ubuntu and gcc. My way of programming in c/c++ is writing the code in a text editor and then compiling it using CLI.

Comment: consider SDL. its portable and fairly straight forward

Comment: Not really, but (1) you can always use text i/o to generate e.g. an svg file, (2) there is an image processing sub-library of Boost, which includes some graphics primitives as I recall, and (3) there is a proposed C++ GUI based on Cairo. And on any given platform you can always access that platform's graphics capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no. [Though Herb Sutter is pushing for it](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/01/n3888), based on a C++ification of [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/). `graphics.h` was never part of Standard C++.

As mentioned by sp2danny in a comment, [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) is another pretty widely used cross platform library you might want to look at. (Although since it is a C library, I personally found it a bit clunky using it from C++, but perfectly workable.)

Comment: does anyone know what's difference from cairomm? or *is* there a cairomm?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The proposal doesn't say anything about [cairomm](http://cairographics.org/cairomm/), but there is this: "Starting from a C API rather than a C++ API also provides the benefit of easier potential malleability. [...] This makes it conceptually easier to consider and approve future proposals to reshape the API since such proposals would not involve changing the design of existing C++ classes, which would almost certainly need to be done if the starting point was a C++ library. "

Comment: If I am not wrong, stuff like Cairo, SDL etc are libraries which extend the functionality of C++ to provide graphics support. The proposal hopes to add the functionality of cairo into c++, so that the devs won't have to use the above libraries for minor graphic requirements.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 does not support graphics (in a standard way, without external libraries).

If you are on Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), there are many ways of doing graphics in C or C++. Notice that most Linux desktops are above [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (which could be replaced, e.g. by [Wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29), in the future). You could use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (with its [graphics framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html)), [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/), [Gtk](http://gtk.org/), etc etc...

You generally would build your program around some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) provided by your [toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) (e.g. Qt).

If you just want to plot some curves or graphs, you could consider [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)-ing some external program like [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) etc... (or generate some [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) and/or HTML ...)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it might help: [Basic Graphics library for gcc/g++ on par with graphics.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026398/basic-graphics-library-for-gcc-g-on-par-with-graphics-h) . The answer I put in.

But for those that want a BGI type interface, I already know what its going to look like.

It will have a socket- or shared-memory based interface to a software graphics engine that will do all the windowing/rendering and stuff. It'll be open-source of course and come with a rock-solid Windows installer. All you have to do to do anything from drawing a few 2D lines to programming the next Xbox game will be to feed it commands.

So let's say you're a dyed-in-the-wool GCC guy like me (CLI's rock!). You just download this Windows program, a PDF manual that tells you what to shoot over whatever pipe you are using (maybe including a pipe...clever, no?), kind of like VRML. But its built to be easy to learn, and you can literally open a socket or whatever and start talking to it. It just displays whatever you send it.